# Can I use SQlite to access MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlite, windows-store-apps

I'm developing windows store app and I have an issue to view data through the app by the way I could able to insert, update and delete the data using developing app. I want to show the data on the windows store app, is there any way to do it?
also i have an idea about SQLite but i never used that so i don't know whether it can access the data from MySQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL and SQLite are NOT the same thing.
you can read [here - www.sqlite.org](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) when you can use SQLite

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sqllite but never execute sql queries from a standalone programm. Its a huge security risk! Execute sql serverside.